# Windows 7 doesn't boot further than a blank screen with only a mouse cursor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation, black-screen-of-death

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Windows 7 boot further than a blank screen with only a mouse cursor?](https://superuser.com/questions/5664/how-do-i-make-windows-7-boot-further-than-a-blank-screen-with-only-a-mouse-cursor)

I am doing a clean install, having tried from both USB and DVD with two different images (32 and 64-bit) and am still receiving this error regardless of which boot options I choose. I've done Safe Mode, Safe Mode with networking, Low Res, and everything else on the list, and yet I am always encountered with the following:

- Boot from USB/DVD, press f8 for alternate boot options
- Choose any of the listed options
- Black screen with grey bar on the bottom shows loading status
- Windows 7 logo fades on screen and starts animating to show further loading
- Logo fades out, and a black screen with mouse appears
- Mouse is able to move, but nothing happens even when left alone for days at a time

I'm tempted to think this is a video card or CPU incompatibility problem, but it had the same version of windows installed before I decided to reinstall.

I'm working with a Compaq Presario CQ61-411WM laptop.

Comment: "any of the listed options" includes at least one option entitled "Enable Boot Logging", which would have of course made the question more informative.

Comment: I can't discern the contents of the log without an operating system or a working command prompt of some sort. I can't even get to it.

Comment: You **have** an operating system with a working command prompt.  [Your installation disc is not scotch mist, you know.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-7)

Comment: I can't get that far in the installation for that to matter, I black screen before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two monitors hooked up?  Reboot with only one and finish installing.  I have had this happen to me.

Comment: It's only one, might be thinking there are two displays when there aren't though. How would I check for/fix that?