# Windows 7 does not show login screen, only the mouse

Tags: windows-7, boot, autodesk-inventor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Windows 7 boot further than a blank screen with only a mouse cursor?](https://superuser.com/questions/5664/how-do-i-make-windows-7-boot-further-than-a-blank-screen-with-only-a-mouse-curso)

While installing Autodesk Inventor 2010 on my Windows 7 laptop, my system froze.

Since that incident, it won't start again. I end up on a black screen with only the mouse visible. The same happens in safemode.
I already tried the ideas mentioned on [How do I make Windows 7 boot further than a blank screen with only a mouse cursor?](https://superuser.com/questions/5664/how-do-i-make-windows-7-boot-further-than-a-blank-screen-with-only-a-mouse-curso) without success...
Any ideas?

Comment: did not see that, but it does not help at all^^

Comment: yup, none of that works for me...

Comment: Would be good to [edit] your question and add a list of what you've tried and that you've seen the duplicates, so it won't get closed.

Comment: Perhaps update your question with all that you've tried (and the results) so that there will be a better chance that this will be considered a different question (doubtful).  Otherwise consider adding a bounty to the other question to garner better answers.

Answer (score -1):

I would see if the computer can boot in safe mode, if it does.  See if you can uninstall autodesk.

Comment: Quote from the question: *> The same happens in safemode*

Comment: as I said, safemode does not help, is gets stuck at the same place